# Using static constexpr member variables as template method parameters

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm trying to simplify some template code by defining some information about the class as static constexpr members. Here's a much simplified example:

```cpp
template <typename _Tp>
class Test
{
public:
    static constexpr bool is_array = std::is_array_v<_Tp>;

    template <typename U = _Tp, typename std::enable_if_t<!is_array>>* dummy = nullptr>
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "It's not an array\n";
    }

    template <typename U = _Tp, typename std::enable_if_t<is_array>>* dummy = nullptr>
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "It's an array\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<char[]>().print();
    Test<char>().print();
}
```

Clang says

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/type_traits:2385:44: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
    using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
                                           ^~~~~
test.cc:11:49: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'enable_if_t' requested here
    template <typename U = _Tp, typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_array>>
                                                ^
test.cc:26:5: note: in instantiation of template class 'Test<char []>' requested here
    Test<char[]>().print();
```

It works if I fully qualify `is_array`, as in `Test<U>::is_array`, but I have several template parameters, and doing it that way seems like it'd make it even messier.

Is there a way to do what I'm after, besides using a macro?

Comment: How about a single `print()` with `if constexpr` branches inside?

Comment: @bipll Yes, that would work in this case. I'd have to combine a bunch of SFINAE selected methods into large ones, with if constexpr's. It does compile and work, though. I was looking for a way to just have the compiler select the right method.

Comment: I ended up refactoring my code to better use if constexpr, that seemed like the cleanest way to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that SFINAE works for a method of a class, you have to have a test based over a specific template parameter of the method (so `U`, in your case).

If you check `is_array`, if depends from `_Tp` (the template parameter of the class), not from `U`.

But, if you can use at least C++14, you can have template variables, so you can templatize `is_array`

```
template <typename U>
static constexpr bool is_array = std::is_array_v<U>;
```

This simplify a little

You can also remove the `typename` before `std::enable_if_t` (thanks the `_t`) and cancel `dummy` (that is unused).

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Test
 {
   template <typename U>
   static constexpr bool is_array = std::is_array_v<U>;

   template <typename U = T,
             std::enable_if_t<not is_array<U>>* = nullptr>
   void print()
    { std::cout << "It's not an array\n"; }

   template <typename U = T,
             std::enable_if_t<is_array<U>>* = nullptr>
   void print()
    { std::cout << "It's an array\n"; }
 };

int main()
{
    Test<char[]>().print();
    Test<char>().print();
}
```

An alternative (maybe better) is use a `bool` template parameter instead of `U`; for example

```
template <typename T>
struct Test
 {
   static constexpr bool is_array = std::is_array_v<T>;

   template <bool B = is_array,
             std::enable_if_t<not B>* = nullptr>
   void print()
    { std::cout << "It's not an array\n"; }

   template <bool B = is_array,
             std::enable_if_t<B>* = nullptr>
   void print()
    { std::cout << "It's an array\n"; }
 };
```

Comment: That works and isn't too far off. I have several bools I'd want to use, and was hoping to avoid passing them all in. If I did it with a template constexpr, I'd have to pass in several types, which is still going to get messy, but I could shorten more complex expressions I suppose.